# Question regarding the timing of prayers

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, salat-al-qasr

Assalam Alaikum, my dear brothers, and sisters of Islam. I am 16 years old and have an interest in playing outdoor sports. Our playtime starts at 4 pm but the asr prayer's time is 4:46 pm. I wanted to ask that can I pray before 4:46 to go out early and have more time to play? Also, I wanted to add that there is a Masid near our ground, but my family is not yet convinced to send me to the Masjid as there are many people there.
Please can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Is the prayer congregation @ 4:46PM or does the Asr time start from 4:46pm? If the latter than you can't pray before the Asr time begins.

Answer (score 1):

**Can I pray before Asr time to go out early and have more time to play?**

No. It is not allowed to intentionally pray before the time of prayer starts. If you do that, your prayer of Asr would not be valid. It would not count, and it would be obligatory to do it again when the time actually starts.

Allah says:

> Indeed, prayer has been decreed upon the believers a decree of specified times. (4:103)

Either try to finish your play time before Maghrib starts so you have time to pray Asr or delay starting your play time until after Asr time starts and you pray it. Another possibility is for you to take a break in between your play time and do wudhu and pray then.